# then statement not running in angular promise

Tags: angularjs

In my application, a user clicks a button which triggers `runsOnClick`. In `runsOnClick`, I try to use a promise to call `someFunc` (this happens as expected) and once `someFunc` has finished running, I'm expecting this code (the `then` part of the promise) inside `runsOnClick` to run but it never does

```
then(function() {
          console.log("in runsOnClick");//this never runs, why?
         });
```

How do I structure a promise so that all the code in `runsOnClick` runs?

```
  $scope.someFunc = function(){
    console.log("in someFunc");
    $http.get('http://localhost:8090/endpoint').success(function(data){
      console.log(data, "this logs");
      });
  },
  $scope.runsOnClick = function(){

     $scope.someFunc().then(function() {
      console.log("in runsOnClick");//this never runs, why?
     });
  },
```

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the return statement:

```
  $scope.someFunc = function(){
    console.log("in someFunc");
    //  v----------------------------- here 
    return $http.get('http://localhost:8090/endpoint').success(function(data){
      console.log(data, "this logs");
    });
  },
```

Your attempt to call `.then()` is probably failing with a TypeError because the return value of `$scope.someFunc()` is `undefined`.

Comment: `$q` shouldn't fail with a `TypeError`, it will just pass `undefined` to the following `then` callback.

Comment: @DavinTryon `undefined.then(...)` will fail with a `TypeError` because `undefine` doesn't have a `then` method. The error will not come from $q.

Comment: Ah, though you meant the `next` taking `undefined` as the callback param.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return` something for the `next` to run:

```
  return $http.get('http://localhost:8090/endpoint').success(function(data){
      console.log(data, "this logs");
  });
```